# Working with Flex ComboBox

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, combobox

In Flex, we can create a combobox with this:

```
<s:ComboBox id="mycb" dataProvider="{data}" labelField="name" change="combobox1_changeHandler(event)"/>
```

But, how can I access the value of the combobox? I tried with `mycb.textInput.text` but it seems doesn't work well. If I use `mycb.selectedItem.name`, it will dispatch error if user manually type in a value that is not in the list.

So, how can I get the value of the combobox which it's value may or may not be in the drop down list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is correct that "mycb.selectedItem.name". In "change handler" always check for the not null like if(mycb.selectedItem!=null). Then the error will not appear. Ensure your "labelfield" matches the variable in data provider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If it is null, then how can I get the value?

Comment: so you need both dataprovider value & manual value right. In that case i doesn't think any facility is available for combobox. But there is an alternate way. In combobox you can show others, If a user choose others then display textiput & get the value from there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [example in the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ComboBox.html#includeExamplesSummary) for `ComboBox`. Note how they use the [labelToItemFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ComboBox.html#labelToItemFunction) to handle the case when the user types something that is not in the dataProvider.

You can use this function to return an object that has the custom value in it. Then let your existing change handler process the custom value just like the ones in the dataProvider.

```
<!-- Function to handle custom input strings -->                        
private function myLabelToItemFunction(input:String):*
{
    <!-- Returns object that matches items in dataProvider -->
    return {ingredient:input, category:"mystery"};
}
```